# После изменения данных в SQL базе они не сразу читаются

Tags: c#, linq2sql

.Net Core, MVC-6, EF-7
записываю данные в Postgres SQL:

```
db.SaveChanges();
db.Database.CommitTransaction();
```

После этого пытаюсь прочитать эти данные с помощью LINQ-SQL - записанных данных нет.
Перезагружаю страницу - т.е. новый запрос - записанные данные с помощью LINQ-SQL читаются!

Собственно вопрос - почему записанные данные не читаются после записи и что нужно сделать чтоб читались?

Весь код в одной функции. Ни каких Async и await.

```
db.Database.BeginTransaction();
```

Измняю базу:

```
List<License> DelLicenses = db.Licenses
    .Where(u => u.UserId == UserId && u.ProductId == ProductId).ToList(); 
db.RemoveRange(DelLicenses); 
db.SaveChanges(); 
....; 
db.SaveChanges();
db.Database.CommitTransaction();
```

И вот здесь не читается:

```
List<License> DelLicenses = db.Licenses
  .Where(u => u.UserId == UserId && u.ProductId == ProductId).ToList();
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример кода, что вы делаете и в какой последовательности

Comment: db.Database.BeginTransaction();

Comment: Весь код в одной функции. Ни каких Async и await. db.Database.BeginTransaction();Измняю базу: List<License> DelLicenses = db.Licenses.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId && u.ProductId == ProductId).ToList();  db.RemoveRange(DelLicenses); db.SaveChanges(); ....; db.SaveChanges();db.Database.CommitTransaction(); И вот здесь не читается: ist<License> DelLicenses = db.Licenses.Where(u => u.UserId == UserId && u.ProductId == ProductId).ToList();

Comment: ЗЫ: как форматировать коменты хоть убей не знаю как.

Comment: Ситуацию подтверждаю - тоже с этим сталкивался. Убрал теги `asp.net-core` и `.net-core`, потому что баг (?) не специфичен для этих платформ. Добавил тэг `linq2sql`